# Execute bash script loop without exit on error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

What I am trying to do is to run several hadoop jobs for each data set in a folder. I am using a loop like this below:

```
    hdfs dfs -ls | grep -o '[0-9]*x[0-9]*$'|while read line;
    do
    echo "Operator: Spark KMeans, Dataset: $line"
    ./bspark.sh spark_kmeans $line 6 20
    sleep 30s 
    done
```

Some jobs may fail. Is it possible to continue to the next line if an error occurs?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking - the while will just continue to loop if an error occurs in "some_other_script.sh" unless you explicitly tell it to exit.

Comment: The loop will continue with the next iteration regardless (unless you run your script with `set -e`, in which case please update your question with this absolutely crucial detail).

Comment: Also, [don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @tripleee I run it for a number of data sets but it stopped for some reason without reach the other iterations.

Comment: Since the outer loop is a `while read`, if `./bspark.sh` consumes the rest of standard input, that will terminate the loop.  Could that be happening in the failure case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few of things I can think of:

- Your `while` loop is using *STDIN*. I wonder if `bspark.sh` is also using *STDIN* and may be eating your input.
- Is the `bspark.sh` somehow killing your program?
- Is your while loop parsing doing what you think?

A couple of things you can try:

- Put an `echo` in front of your `bspark.sh` line. Instead of actually exeucting `bspark.sh` see what the command looks like. This will give you an idea what the script is actually doing.
- Use `set -xv` which turns on shell debugging. The `-v` shows you the command line before the shell interpolates it, and the `-x` shows you the command line after the shell messes with it. You can set `$PS4` to `\$LINENO>`  to see the line numbers when the debug info prints. Gives you an idea where the errors are occurring.

  The `set +xv` turns off debugging. I find it useful to add these to various places through out my shell scripts to see what's going on.

Comment: `bspark.sh` executes a spark job with the `spark-submit` command. Actually it's a scala program.